# What's the difference between "will know", "knew", and "have/has known"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, will-would

The excerpt below is taken from *Advanced Grammar in Use*:

> We can use **will** to draw conclusions or state assumptions about
> things that are the case now.
>
> - You **will** know that Ewan and Lucy are engaged. (= I assume you already know)

The writer's explanation given in parentheses, in my view, implies that the the person that the person being spoken to (which the pronoun **you** refers to) knew about the fact that Ewan and Lucy are engaged *according to the speaker's assumption*.
Can I equivalently also write these instead (for convenient reason, I add the question tags that have decreased tone):

> You knew that Ewan and Lucy are engaged, didn't you?

> You've known that Ewan and Lucy are engaged, haven't you?

Comment: I don't find it natural to use _You've known_ unless there is something else added. "You've known [it] for some time, haven't you?" "You've known [it] all along, haven't you?" (meaning 'all the time that their other friends have been wondering about their relationship').

Comment: We'd normally use Simple Present to ask something where the expected answer is "Yes". But ***you would know that***, wouldn't you?

Answer (score -1):

> You knew that Ewan and Lucy are engaged, didn’t you?

This sentence is possible since knew is past and the contraction after the comma has to be:

1. Past
2. Are

> You’ve known that Ewan and Lucy are engaged, have you?

This sentence is wrong. Since the contraction after the comma has to be opposite, it should be like that.

> You’ve known that Evan and Lucy are engaged, haven’t you?

[**For more information**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/contractions)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I didn't notice that before. Apart from that, what about their difference with the usage of 'will know' related to the title?

Comment: @user516076 let’s say you’re writing a question with contractions, specifically ‘will’
You have to write the contraction after the comma the opposite way. Take this example: “You’ll help James, won’t you?” Won’t is the opposite of you’ll.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I'm asking. I understood the question tag and I should apologize for making mistake in the question I wrote. The problem is, I want to know the different usage between *will know*, *have/has known*, and *knew* in the sense of drawing conclusions/assumptions about things that are the case now.

Comment: Sorry.  Has vs Have. https://writingexplained.org/has-vs-have-difference The past tense of has is had. Has is singular, present tense. Had is singular or plural, past.

Comment: Will know means that you did not not know it in the past but you know it now. 
Has or had known means that you knew it in the past and you still know it now. 
Ok?

Comment: @Genie: NO! - That's *completely* wrong! In conversational contexts, ***You will know** [that Ewan and Lucy are engaged, whatever]* has no real connection to Past, Present, or Future. It's ***oblique / deferential circumlocution***, often used to place some "distance" between the speaker and his words. To some extent, it's a "frozen form", but the underlying implication is usually something along the lines of *I wouldn't be so crass as to ask you **directly** whether you know this (which I'm sure you do), but **if I were to ask you**, obviously you **would** know*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m not a native so what would it be?

Comment: @Genie What you call "contractions" are actually called "tag questions". This make your answer and comments below difficult to understand